# Form shouldn't contain extra fields Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to understand how Symfony works, so I tried to create two forms on the same page: one form for the firstname and the other for the email (I want two different forms so two different submit buttons).

I have the error `This form should not contain extra fields.`with Symfony 4 after I submit the form. The invalid value is the email.The violation message says "`{{ extra_fields }}" => ""email"`"

I read in the Symfony documentation that I have to enable the option `allow_extra_fields`.

So this is what I tried :

```
$emailForm = $this->createFormBuilder(['allow_extra_fields' => true])
                          ->add('email'  )
                          ->add('Submit',SubmitType::class)
                          ->getForm();
```

but it didn't work. How can I remove the error message ? There are a few previous posts about the error but the version 4 of Symfony seems to work differently.

This is a bit more of code :

```
       $userForm = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
                    ->add('firstname', TextType::class)
                    ->add('email', EmailType::class)
                    ->add('description', TextType::class)
                    ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class)
                    ->getForm();

      $userForm->handleRequest($request);

       $defaultData = ['pass' => '', 'conf_pass' => ''];
       $passForm = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
                ->add('pass', PasswordType::class, ['label' => 'Change password'])
                ->add('conf_pass', PasswordType::class, ['label' => 'Confirm password'])
                ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class)
                ->getForm();

      $passForm->handleRequest($request);
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that I am handling two times, but I'm not sure at all ...

Comment: would you possibly show more of the code handling the request and the template where the form is rendered?

Comment: I just added some code !

Comment: I think I have to make a condition to know which form to handle but how ?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to actually [use form classes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes). They are not hard to do, and they work very nicely overall. For example if you create a form type called UserType, the form fields will all be named like `user[firstname]` and so on. the handleRequest will also automatically pick them up and not stumble over the other forms potentially posted data. Then instead of creating a form builder in your controller, you call

```
$userForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class);
$userForm->handleRequest($request); // as before.
```

after that the `if($userForm->isSubmitted() && $userForm->isValid())` check is very much enough to find out, which form was submitted.

(also, if you didn't know: you can only submit one form at a time anyway ;o)

However, I hope you're not doing too much custom form rendering. If you still would want to render your forms manually `{{ userForm.firstname.vars.name }}` should give you the form fields name (or maybe `...vars.id`, i never can remember)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I am going to try this right know !